# function name vs variable in haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax

> From haskell documentation:
>
> > Identifiers are lexically distinguished into two namespaces (Section 1.4): those that begin with a lower-case letter (**variable
> >     identifiers**) and those that begin with an upper-case letter
> >     (**constructor identifiers**).

So a variable containing a constant value, i.e `a=4` and the function name add `add a b = a + b` are both variable identifiers, true? Can we say that a function name is variable?

> From another academic source:
>
> ```
> f (patter1)...(pattern2) = expression
> ```
>
> > ..where a pattern can be constructor or a variable, not a defined
> >     function

This is where I get confused. As I can do `f g x` where g is a function, I again see that a function name is a variable then. True?
What do they mean with "not a defined defined function" then?

Comment: No idea. The second source is probably misleading or poorly worded. Regardless, if one of your parameters to f had the same name as a defined function, that definition would simply be shadowed.

Comment: I think they're trying to contrast with Prolog and friends, where you can do things like `foo (bar baz) = quux`, which means "when calling `foo`, search for a value `baz` for which `bar baz` outputs the input to `foo`, then output `quux`". Haskell doesn't do such generalized search; only obviously injective functions -- constructors -- can be "reversed" in this way.

Answer (score 6):

A function name can be a variable identifier, except when it is an operator like `+`.

This is a statement about **lexical** matters.
You can't infer from that that a function name is a variable. (Because a variable is not a lexical thing.)

It is the other way around, like in

```
f . g = \a -> f (g a)
```

where `f` and `g` are variables, i.e. names that are bound to some unknown-in-advance values, but we know that those values must be functions.

Comment: Infix operators still can be just as "variable" as lowercase identifiers, you just can't use them in pattern matches. But e.g. `foldr f q (x:xs) = f q <:> fqu where { (<:>) = f; fqu = foldr f xs }` is fine.

Comment: Thanks. However, I dont get what you mean with "a variable is not a lexical thing"

Comment: "lexical" refers to how we write it, which is different from "semantic"concerns (what it means). A variable is a semantic object, a reference that is assigned a value. A variable *identifier* is its name, a text representation, about which we can make lexical statements like "doesn't start with a capital letter".

Comment: @leftaroundabout Actually you can sometimes use operator identifiers in pattern matches.  For example this is a legal definition: ``(*) `on` f = \x y -> f x * f y``

Comment: @leftaroundabout You're right. I just didn't want to complicate matters further.

Answer (score 0):

A named function is indeed just a global variable who's "value" just happens to be a function. For example,

```
id x = x
```

can just as well be written as

```
id = ( \ x -> x )
```

Haskell explicitly makes no distinction between these two. Even the type signature says it:

```
id :: x -> x
```

So `id` is just a value who's value has type `x -> x` (i.e., a function).

Somebody else said something about operators not being variables; this is untrue.

```
let (<+>) = \ x y -> (x+y)/(x*y) in 5 <+> 6
```

You can even do something utterly horrifying like write a loop where the contents of `<+>` changes each time through the loop. (But why in the hell would anybody ever do that?)